# Cannot share the internet connection with dual wan setup on RB2011UiAS-RM

Tags: load-balancing, failover, mikrotik, routeros

I have a bit trouble with setting up multiple WAN connections on my RB2011UiAS-RM. Recently we have bought this router to replace an old proxy server in our company, which could fail/broke at any moment (even if it's working fine since ages it's already time for a change).

Both ISPs give us 16 static IP addresses for keeping the linux servers public and for internet connection on all workstations. I want to clarify, these servers are accessed only by my workmates, so the traffic is fairly low, and mostly going inside LAN.

I don't want to share what ISPs IP addresses are in use, so please assume this configuration:

WAN1 - network 192.168.1.160/28, gateway 192.168.1.161, broadcast 192.168.1.175

WAN2 - network 192.168.2.64/28, gateway 192.168.2.65, broadcast 192.168.2.79

LAN:
Routers, APs, Other devices: 10.1.3.0/24 static, 
Servers: 10.1.4.0/24 static, 
Workstations: 10.1.5.0/24 DHCP

My current configuration is based on this PCC manual (https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:PCC) and a config file given by a friend. Dual WAN works fine on the router itself. I can ping anything, and when I disable WAN1 the router automatically switches to WAN2.

The goal is to:

- Give access to the internet on every computer and server on the network - Now it just doesn't work. I can't ping or access anything from any computer (problems with firewall or nat configuration?).
- Pass all other IP addresses on one of the gigabit ethernet ports, and maybe one IP on the second. - I want to combine LAN and external, static IPs for use with virtual interfaces on our servers.

Here is my current configuration: https://pastebin.com/hRw1w1Aq

I have asked my second friend for some help, but unfortunately for him it's the first time he sees dual WAN configuration. My current experience with mikrotik and routeros is limited to hAP ac lite router for some home experiments and SXT Lite5.

Thank you for any helpful comments.

Comment: The problem is now solved (months ago) after doing the same steps on mikrotik's wiki again. We decided to go for failover only, since load balancing gave us some weird behaviour with fasttrack option enabled (probably some unfixed bug in routeros).

The internet is backed by router with LTE modem.

Answer (score 0):

You have ether1-5 ports swiched together (ether2 as master port) and this switchgroup is bridged together with the sfp port and ether6 for some reason. This makes not much sense in the first place.

It is not clear that the three LAN subnet is physically connected to the router on three separate ethernet ports or with a single UTP cable only. You should remove the "master-port" setting from the ethernet ports and add the ethernet ports to the bridge. Then assign the LAN addresses to the bridge. Or if you have three separate physical connections from the LAN subnets then remove the bridge itself and set the IP addresses to the appropriate ethernet interfaces.